# Adding a second button next to the shop button Woocommerc

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

So what my clients wants is on the shop page, on each product there to be a second button next to the shop button. This button should lead to a custom for each product pdf file, that the client can download wihtout the need to enter the exact product page itself.
I am new to  developing and this is a bit hard for me so if you guys and girls can help me i will be extremely thankful :)

Comment: what is the shop  button? Are you talking about **add to cart** or **select options** button?

Comment: yes, it is the  add to cart button on the main shop page, where normaly all the products are displayed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is tested with 2019 theme. Open the functions.php file of your active theme and drop this code at end of the file.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'wpse2019_add_pdf_download_button', 10 );
function wpse2019_add_pdf_download_button() {
    global $product;

    if( $product ) {
        printf( '<a href="%s" class="pdf-button button btn" role="button">%s</a>', "YOUR PDF LINK HERE", __( 'DWONLOAD PDF', 'text-domain' ) );
    }
}
```

default **add to cart** and **select options** buttons are adding via **woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item** hook (source: templates/archive-product.php). I use the same hook and add the 2nd custom button. You will replace **YOUR PDF LINK HERE** with your PDF link.

If you will add different PDF file for every product, you will use the custom field logic. You can use the WordPress native custom field option or some free plugin like ACF/PODs/CMB2 etc

Assume your custom field would be **wc_product_pdf_file**. Then you can try this code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'wpse2019_add_pdf_download_button', 10 );
function wpse2019_add_pdf_download_button() {
    global $product;

    if( $product ) {
        $pdf_link = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'wc_product_pdf_file', true );
        if( ! empty( $pdf_link ) ) {
            printf( '<a href="%s" class="pdf-button button btn" role="button">%s</a>', $pdf_link, __( 'DWONLOAD PDF', 'text-domain' ) );
        }
    }
}
```

**get_post_meta** function is fetching the post meta data. **$product->get_id()** is giving the current product ID.

**Note:** Before editing the file, you keep a backup of your theme.

Comment: Please accept the answer.